# How to show the profile picture in the header of the Microsoft List form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I have a Microsoft List with a Person column called Picture and with the setting Show Picture to True. I have copied the example header code from the Microsoft site Which shows some other picture.
How can  i replace this picture with the profile picture stored in the column Picture.

The header Example code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-header
I know i have to replace the line **"iconName": "Group"** and change it to get the profile picture from the column Picture.

How can I do that? Does anyone know the code?

Comment: You will have to use the `img` element instead of div element with iconName. I will provide the full JSON once I open my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this JSON:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralTertiary"
  },
  "style": {
    "width": "99%",
    "border-top-width": "0px",
    "border-bottom-width": "1px",
    "border-left-width": "0px",
    "border-right-width": "0px",
    "border-style": "solid",
    "margin-bottom": "16px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "align-items": "center"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "=getUserImage([$PersonColumn.email], 's')",
            "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary"
          },
          "style": {
            "flex": "none",
            "padding": "0px",
            "padding-left": "0px",
            "height": "36px"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
      },
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "width": "100%",
        "text-align": "left",
        "padding": "21px 12px",
        "overflow": "hidden"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "='Contact details for ' + [$Title]"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `PersonColumn` is the name of your person or group column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code i have used the internalname whichs is "Foto" which is an Person column. But i get an empty profile picture. And the user has a profile picture set. Gr. P.

Comment: I have tried but no luck with this code: "src": "=@currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$personIterator.email]",
 "src": "=@currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$Foto.email]",
"src": "$Foto.email",

Comment: I did a test if it shows my profilepicture by adding:  "src": "=getUserImage(@me, 's')" and it works but i need the name in the Peron column "Foto" and not myself.

Comment: Is your person column of type single selection or multiple selection is allowed? Also, make sure you are using correct **internal name** of your column in place of `` in JSON I provided above. Find the internal name of your SharePoint person column by following: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/

Comment: I have used the powershell script you have posted. And the internalname of "Foto" is the same as the normal name "Foto". And the column Foto is a single selection.